# Update con subconsulta MySQL,

Tags: mysql

Tengo un proyecto donde tengo que realizar un `update` de una tabla campo *(activa)* , prácticamente tengo algo así :

```
UPDATE 
t1 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT 
  MAX(id) 
FROM
  t2_copy 
GROUP BY idq
ORDER BY idq DESC)AS x2
SET activa = TRUE 
WHERE x2.id
```

copié la tabla para crear una subconsulta . a partir de el y hacer un `inner join` para incluirla y donde el `id_max` sea igual que el id  actualizar

Pero me marca error de que no conoce `x2.id` por ejemplo como si no aceptara el alias.

Comment: Tal vez te falta nombrar la columna en el subselect?  Ej: `SELECT 
  MAX(id) as 'Id' ...`

Comment: no le falta algo al where? tipo x2.id = algo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como no le asignastes un alias al valor devuelto en tu tabla derivada, MySQL automáticamente le asigna un nombre que corresponde a la expresión en el `SELECT`.  O sea, en este caso, el nombre de la columna es literalmente `MAX(id)`.

O sea, que en teoría pudieras referenciar la columna usando:

```
WHERE x2.`MAX(id)` = ...
```

Por supuesto, eso se ve un poco ridículo y no es práctico. Así que lo mejor es que tu le asignes el nombre que quieras con la claúsula `AS`:

```
SELECT MAX(id) as id
```

... para que puedas hacer referencia a ella de la forma esperada:

```
WHERE x2.id = ...
```

Comment: si lo note muy tarde . jaja igual te agradezco mucho tu respuesta .